# Scraping with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a code in python in order to scrape some data from trip advisor(ratings from the reviews). The problem is that whenever I run the code it gives me different rows and never scraps all the webpages.

The index error that appears is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/thimios/PycharmProjects/TripadvisorScrapping/proxiro.py", line 26, in <module>
    rating = soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'rating reviewItemInline'})[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code is the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import urllib.request

file2 = open(os.path.expanduser(r"~/Desktop/TripAdviser Reviews2.csv"), "wb")        
file2.write(b"Organization,Rating" + b"\n")

WebSites = [
"https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g189400-d198932-Reviews-Hilton_Athens-Athens_Attica.html#REVIEWS"]

Checker ="REVIEWS"

# looping through each site until it hits a break
for theurl in WebSites:
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    #print(soup)

    while True:
        # Extract ratings from the text reviews
        altarray = ""
        for i in range(0,10):
            rating = soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'rating reviewItemInline'})[i]
            rating1 = rating.find_all("span")[0]
            rating2 = rating1['class'][1][-2:]
            print(rating2)
            if len(altarray) == 0:
                altarray = [rating2]
            else:
                altarray.append(rating2)

            #print(altarray)
            #print(len(altarray))
            #print(type(altarray))

            # Extract Organization,
            Organization1 = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'heading_name'})
            Organization = Organization1.text.replace('"', ' ').replace('Review of',' ').strip()
            #print(Organization)



            # Loop through each review on the page
            for x in range(0, 10):
                Rating = altarray[x]
                Rating = str(Rating)
                #print(Rating)
                #print(type(Rating))

                Record2 = Organization + "," + Rating
                if Checker == "REVIEWS":
                    file2.write(bytes(Record2, encoding="ascii", errors='ignore') + b"\n")

                link = soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "nav next rndBtn ui_button primary taLnk"})
                #print(link)
                #print(link[0])
                if len(link) == 0:
                    break
                else:
                   soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.tripadvisor.com" + link[0].get('href')),"html.parser")
                   #print(soup)
                   #print(Organization)
                   print(link[0].get('href'))
                   Checker = link[0].get('href')[-7:]
                   #print(Checker)

        file2.close()
```

I am supposing that trip advisor doesn't give full access to the data.Any idea?

Comment: Minor terminology correction: The term is "scrape" and "scraping".

Answer (score 0):

The error is encountered when you are trying to access an element in the list by index and that index does not exists.

I have ran your code and it prints :

```
50
50
50
50
50
50
40
40
40
50
```

Although, the way you are looping is not the most pythonic way of doing it  and also susceptible to lot of index errors.

What you can do is replace this :

```
for i in range(0,10):
    rating = soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'rating reviewItemInline'})[i]
```

with :

```
for rating in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'rating reviewItemInline'}) :
```

This shall resolve the error as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help . I try your way and yes it runs faster !!!! but again the same problem at the page 40 it crashed again with the following message:                                                                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/thimios/PycharmProjects/TripadvisorScrapping/proxiro.py", line 40, in <module>
    Organization = Organization1.text.replace('"', ' ').replace('Review of',' ').strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Now, this is not the same error as the one you reported earlier. This one is because Organization1 value is '`None`' as there is no element with class exactly equal to `"heading_name"`. Earlier one was because you were trying to access a non existent index location.

Comment: Try printing values before the lines errors are encountered which may help you out in faster debugging. Also, try to understand the different meanings of different errors and why are you encountering them.

Comment: Try replacing `heading_name` with `heading_height` as this is a static class name.